# Simple group problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am reading a book of algebra and I have a difficulty in understanding one thing.
In the book it is written there is no simple group of order 528 and the explanation is as follows.

Let $H$ be a Sylow 11-subgroup. Then $n_{11}=12$, which I understood why, and $|N(H)|=44$ and $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_{12}$.

Could you please explain?

Comment: I don't believe your book says that there are no groups of order $528$.  There are cyclic groups of all orders, if nothing else.  Perhaps you left some information off?

Comment: Oh, was the header meant to suggest to us that you were looking for simple groups of order $528$?  I imagined that the header just meant that you considered the problem to be less than difficult.

Comment: In the book it is written that there is no *simple* group of order $528$? And $n_{11}$ is probably the number of Sylow $11$-subgroups of that group? In general, the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of a group $G$ is the index of the normalizer of one of them: $n_p = \lvert G: N_G (P) \rvert$, where $P$ is some Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Okay I got it . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For the subgroup of $A_{12}$ part, note that $G$ acts transitively by conjugation on the $12$ Sylow $11$-subgroups. Consider the Kernel of this action - it is a normal subgroup and the action is non-trivial, so given $G$ is simple, the Kernel must be the trivial subgroup, and the image is isomorphic to $G$. The image is contained in $S_{12}$ because it consists of permutations of the $12$ subgroups.

Now if the image contained an odd permutation, it would have a subgroup of index $2$ and this subgroup would be normal. But the image is known to be simple, so therefore cannot contain any odd permutations, so must be wholly contained in $A_{12}$.

I have sketched over some parts of this which you should already know. The technique of looking at the action on of $G$ on the Sylow subgroups as a homomorphism to the relevant symmetric group is likely to come up again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a group of order 528 - in fact, there are 170 of them up to isomorphism.

See here:

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_528

Comment: I want to know how $|N(H)|=44$?